# Does it means a high accuracy of model will have high confidence score

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to select a model from different CNN trained models based on some parameter.
Initially, I was considering using model confidence score to decide which model is better. Now I am considering using accuracy for the selection of a good model among other models. I need to ask is there a relation between accuracy and confidence score, does it means high accuracy leads to high confidence score and vice versa. Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you call confidence score ? And why are you using it as the metric to decide which model is the best. It is much more common to use accuracy metric to decide which model is the best. If you want to go further and accuracy metric is not good enough, than I would use ROC curves or this kind of stuff.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ubikuity, by confidence score I mean probability output of CNN model, probabilities returns by softmax layer.

Comment: Yup, I would say again that confidence score doesn't seem a great indicator to me, idk why you are using it, accuracy is usually considered the best metric and I've never heard of using confidence score.

Comment: @Ubikuity, thanks a lot really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by confidence score you mean the probability output of your CNN then you have to consider if your models are well calibrated. A well calibrated model is one that a confidence score of, e.g. 0.8 implies 80% accuracy. Another way to think about it is that if you get 100 predictions of class 0 with a confidence score of 0.8, then 80 of those predictions should indeed be of class 0. A specific type of plot, a 'calibration curve', can help you identify that. The above answer the question about the relation between the score and accuracy.

Now, in practical applications, you might not want to use the confidence score as a measure of performance. That is because of effects such as covariate shift and concept drift which have an unpredictable effect on the confidence scores.

Comment: Thanks alot really helpful @LuckyLuke, by confidence score I mean probability output of my CNN model.